# Returning A<List<Foo>> from builder

Tags: java, generics

In my code, I want to use typed parameters like so:

```
public static final ParameterDefinition<List<String>> NAMES
    = ParameterDefinition.build( List.class, CURRENCY );
```

This allows me later to write:

```
List<String> names = object.get( NAMES );
```

without any cases.

But it doesn't compile (`List` isn't compatible to `List<String>`).

I can get the code to compile with:

```
@SuppressWarnings( { "unchecked", "rawtypes" } )
public static final ParameterDefinition<List<String>> NAMES
    = (ParameterDefinition) ParameterDefinition.build( List.class, "names" );
```

How can I get rid of the `@SuppressWarnings`? How can I simulate `List<String>.class` in Java 6?

Note: The code on the right hand side can be more complex (i.e. `build(List.class, String.class, "names" )` would be ok) but the left hand side must be exactly as is.

Comment: What does your `build` method look like?

Comment: What is your builders return type?

Comment: I think we're missing most of the relevant code here.

Comment: I.e. What type is `object`? What's the signature of `ParameterDefinition.build()`? What about `object.get()`?

Comment: Why specifically do you want to get rid of `@SuppressWarnings`? The cast is valid and parameterized classes doesn't exist in Java at all due to the type erasure. If the sole intent is to make it the developers easy, look how Google Gson "solved" it with `TypeToken`.

Comment: Java generics _can_ be limiting...

Comment: Does the `ParameterDefinition` need to know the type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the "Note", I take you can change the definition of build(?).
You also did not specify if the `ParameterDefinition` actually needs to know the type.
If it doesn't, this will do the trick:

```
public static <X> ParameterDefinition<X> build(String name);
```

If you need the parameter only because Java sometimes is to stupid to guess the generic types, but it is not used in the method, you could also do

```
public static <X> ParameterDefinition<X> build(Class<? super X> type, String name);
```

If the `ParameterDefinition` uses the type parameter to ensure the type of the value, then you should be aware that there is no possible argument that ensures the result will actually be of `List<String>`. That's probably the reason why there is no simple solution to your problem.

If you don't care, you can do the following:

```
public static <X> ParameterDefinition<X> build(Class<X> type, String name) { ... }

@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
public static <X> Class<List<X>> listOf(Class<X> itemType) {
    return (Class) List.class;
}

static ParameterDefinition<String> = build(String.class, "name");
static ParameterDefinition<List<String>> = build(listOf(String.class), "keywords");
```

The advantage here is that the `SuppressWarnings` are in the library code and the API user doesn't have to deal with them.

If it is actually important that all elements of the list are String, and I assume that your implementation is supposed to be extensible, you will need a more complex approach:

```
public interface ArgumentValidator<X> {

    boolean accept(Object o)

}

public static <X> ArgumentValidator<X> instanceOf(Class<X> type) { ... }

public static <X> ArgumentValidator<List<X>> listOf(Class<X> itemType) { ... }

public static <X> ParameterDefinition<X> build(ArgumentValidator<X> validator, String name) { ... }

public static <X> ParameterDefinition<X> build(Class<X> type, String name) {
    return build(instanceOf(type), name);
}

static ParameterDefinition<String> = build(String.class, "name");
static ParameterDefinition<List<String>> = build(listOf(String.class), "keywords");
```

Protip: instead of `ArgumentValidator`, use `org.hamcrest.Matcher`.

That's all I can think of. Would be nice if you could be a bit more specific about your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

One way might be to introduce subtypes that extend the classes/interfaces and define concrete type parameters, e.g. something like `interface StringList extends List<String>`. Inside the `build` method you'd then be able to get the generic type of the class that has been passed.

The call would then look like this:

```
public static final ParameterDefinition<? extends List<String>> NAMES = ParameterDefinition.build( StringList.class, CURRENCY  );
```

True, that's not quite elegant but might be a start. I'll think a bit more about this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is ParameterDefinition a generic class?  In other words, is it defined as

```
public class ParameterDefinition<T>
```

or something other than

```
public class ParameterDefintion
```

If so, then you can return a `ParameterDefintion<List<String>>`, but if not, you need to decide on what value to place within the `<T>` area.

By the way, adding final to a static method has no effect, and is redundant.  I'd remove it.

After ParameterDefinition takes a Generics parameter, you can write

```
    public static final <X> ParameterDefinition<X> build(Class<X> clazz, String name) {
      ...
      return ...;
    }
```

And you don't even need the cast you had at

```
(ParameterDefinition) ParameterDefinition.build( List.class, "names" );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with `build(List.class, String.class, "names" )`, then you can use `public class ParameterDefinition<T extends List<P>, P>` as the class definition, which will allow creating the class like this `ParameterDefinition<List<String>, String> test = new ParameterDefinition<List<String>, String>();` .

It ain't pretty but it should work and it allows you to define what the `List` contains.